# Sybase Copy rows from 3 tables to a final one

Tags: copy, sybase, rows

I have a job which creates 3 sybase tables on the fly. Thus they are all not indexed. Currently we have no way to index them as we do not have control over them

table1 - 250,000 rows
table2 - 270,000 rows
table3 - 1.2 million rows

Now, I want a job which will combine the results of all the above 3 tables. Basically a copy using some sql statement. I know UNION ALL is solution but it might hog the server as it needs to load millions of records into memory. Is there a way to batch load the final table? If so, can you please let me know how?

Thanks,
RC

Comment: I see that we can use the fetch statement to read n number of rows at a time. I have never been able to read n rows at a time but just one. Any sample would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways:

1. If you have ID's in the tables, go by ranges
   Use a while cycle and do it by sets and do commit in every set.
2. Use cursors
   Without ID's, you can go line by line or, if possible, multiple lines at a time. Just see the most distinct column in it and use it.